# What am I doing wrong with this /testfor command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

It seems like my command won't work, can anyone help me? I spent more than 30 minutes on this command and it still won't work. I put the command in the command block and it lights up, even if there is only 1 player

Here's the command; what am I doing wrong?

```
/testfor @e[team=Red,c=2]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count entities with commands/check if there are only one or a certain number of entities or players left?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/365931/how-to-count-entities-with-commands-check-if-there-are-only-one-or-a-certain-num)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c=2` in 1.12 and `limit=2` in 1.13 is a restriction to **at most** that many entities. So if there are 3 players, it would just select 2. But if there is only 1, it would find that one player.

To put the number of players on a team into a scoreboard called "playerCount", execute this command:

```
/execute store result score dummyPlayer playerCount if entity @e[team=Red]
```

You don't even need a `run` and chained command, since `execute if` without a chained command just gives back the number of matched entities.

`dummyPlayer` is in this command, who would have thought, a dummy player. You can then run commands under the condition that it's higher than or equal to 2 like this:

```
/execute if score dummyPlayer test matches 2.. run <command>
```

Comment: For 1.13 replace `/execute @a[...] ~ ~ ~ ` with `/execute as @a[...]`, same with `@e`.

Comment: I'll properly update this answer to 1.13 at a later point, because I need to check in Minecraft whether I do it right. And when I'm at my PC, I currently have better things to do. :D But just translating the commands here to their 1.13 equivalents works for now, it's just not performance optimised.