# How to count items in a certain radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I want to count items in radius of 10 chunks but I have never made a plugin and I didn't saw a event to count a specific item.
What I want to do is for example: count the amount of cobblestone items on the ground, in chest and in inventories and I want to put that number in a variable. If two players would use the same plugin at the same time. Will it putt the amount of cobblestone of both players in that variable or does the game makes them separate. I really Want it to be separate. I don't want to spoil what I am going to make because I saw that what I am going to make has never been made before(I think) I hope someone can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count entities with commands/check if there are only one or a certain number of entities or players left?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/365931/how-to-count-entities-with-commands-check-if-there-are-only-one-or-a-certain-num)

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 The user to me seems to be indifferent about what technology they use. "I have never made a plugin" reads to me like an unstated assumption that plugins are the only valid solution, not a request to use one.

Comment: What I eventually want to do, isn't possible with command blocks. Okay, I will share what I want to make. I wanna make an afk simulator. It counts the items in a radius of 10 chunks and waits 10 minutes. Then it checks the items again. All the farmable farmable items get saved in variables. After 10 minutes the items get put into other variables. The first ones get subtracted by the second ones. I will multiply that number by 6 and then I have the items per hour. It saves the time when it begun and then kicks the player. The rest of the message will be put underneat

Comment: Now it puts the items in the nearest chest. This can be done by typing /afk again because when you first start it the player get frozen. Those are the basics of the plugin because I know a few ways to exploit it but I first want to get this done. That's why I need a plugin. It is made to save server resources.

Comment: @timpi4ever Could you please edit that into your post?